# Reflection PropertyInfo.GetValue(object) throwing DBNull Exception

Tags: c#, reflection

I am having a difficult time with what should be a simple bit of code. The code below loops through the properties of a custom class and gets the value from that class object and stuffs it in the data row.

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();

foreach(PropertyInfo p in sfa.GetType().GetProperties())
{                    
    row[p.Name] = p.GetValue(sfa);
}
```

The problem is the error I get:

> Cannot set Column 'columnName' to be null. Please use DBNull instead.

The particular column it is choking on is a `DateTime` type property. I am all good with using `DBNull` if that's what it wants. I just don't know and can't figure out HOW? How do I tell the row.column intersection that I want to give it `DBNull` if it doesn't like `System.null`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for `null` or just use null-coalescing operator:

```
 row[p.Name] = p.GetValue(sfa) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: All I can say is that it is late and I have been coding all day.  Sheesh!  I actually did try the ?? DBNull.Value, but not outside the parentheses.  I will accept your answer as soon as time permits.  Thanks Selman22